# AngularJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when ng-repeat a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I am creating an ionic mobile Apps project. I want to display a particular div multiple times in a html page. After that, I would like to display images etc. for each of the div.

Here are my codes snippet:

HTML:

```
   <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1; width:100px; height:100px" ng-style="navigationStyleToilet" ng-repeat="o in arr"></div>
```

controller.js:

```
    for (i = 0; i < categoryInfo.length; i++)
    {

        $scope.arr.push(i);

        var targetImageX = categoryInfo.X;
        var targetImageY = categoryInfo.Y;

        $scope.navigationStyleToilet[i] = {

            "background-image": "url('../img/CurrentLocaton.gif')",
            "background-repeat": "no-repeat",

            "background-position": targetImageX + " " + targetImageY
        }
    }
```

The categoryInfo array looks like this:

```
var categoryInfo= new Array();
categoryInfo[0] = { X: 2, Y: 5 };
categoryInfo[1] = { X: 5, Y: 5 };
categoryInfo[2] = { X: 9, Y: 9 };
categoryInfo[3] = { X: 15, Y: 15 };
```

However, it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". Can someone help me please?

Comment: Initialize your `$scope.arr` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have $scope.arr initialized

```
 $scope.arr = [];
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. Please do take a look as I need additional help from you :) Help me please :)

Comment: you have not added enough code, do you have team viewer?

Comment: @Antoni atually the problem does not lie there

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize your `$scope.arr` first. Push throws exception because you have non-initialized or even not declared array.

```
$scope.arr = [];
...
$scope.arr.push(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add **ng-controller** to the parent element of your current element and
code for assigning an array to **arr** will be like

`var app=angular.module("",[]);
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){$scope.arr =categoryInfo});`

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [];
  var categoryInfo= new Array();
  categoryInfo[0] = { X: 2, Y: 5 };
  categoryInfo[1] = { X: 5, Y: 5 };
  categoryInfo[2] = { X: 9, Y: 9 };
  categoryInfo[3] = { X: 15, Y: 15 };
  for (var i in categoryInfo) {
    $scope.arr.push(categoryInfo[i]);
  }
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="o in arr">{{o.X}}</div>
</div>
```